# MVC - Does this code belong to model, controller or view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have in my site notifications, similar as facebook. But I only have 3 type of notifications:

- [nickname] sent you a new quize [quizename]
- [nickname] added you to his group [groupname]. accept | deny
- You received 100$ credit for login today.

Table notification

notification_id | type | item_id | from_id | to_id | created | notified

item_id represents quize_id or group_id. I make extra joins to get all data.

A problem I have is how to display each notification depends on type. One of options is to organize string for display in controller:

```
foreach($results as $key => $result){
  switch($result['type']){
    case 1:
    $string = "<a href=".baseUrl()."/users/$result['userId']>$result['nickname']</a> "._("wants you to take a quize")." <a href='".baseUrl()."/quize/$result['rel']'>$result['quizeName']</a>";
    break;
    case 2:
    $string = "<a href=".baseUrl()."/users/$result['userId']>$result['nickname']</a> "._("added you to his group")." <a href='".baseUrl()."/group/$result['rel']'>$result['groupName']</a>";
    break;
    case 3:
    $string = _("You received 100 credit for log in today");
  }
  $notifications[$key]['string'] = $string;
}

$data['notifications'] = $notifications;

$this->load->view('views/notifications/last_notification_view', $data);
```

The problem with that method is that part of view is inside controller. I could sent rough data to view, but then the problem is that I need to make similar php code in view. So which method is better? Or is there any other way?

Comment: This is view logic, don't be afraid of having this code on your view, just make sure the controller doesn't generate the actual strings but passes only the necessary data to create them on the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own personal opinion is that you should pass $results to the view, and have the loop that takes results and prints out links inside of view. What you should have is this in controller:

```
$data['notifications']=$results;
$this->load->view('views/notifications/last_notification_view', $data);
```

and this in view:

```
foreach($data['notifications'] as $key => $result){
  switch($result['type']){
    case 1:
    echo "<a href=".baseUrl()."/users/$result['userId']>$result['nickname']</a> "._("wants you to take a quize")." <a href='".baseUrl()."/quize/$result['rel']'>$result['quizeName']</a>";
    break;
    case 2:
    echo "<a href=".baseUrl()."/users/$result['userId']>$result['nickname']</a> "._("added you to his group")." <a href='".baseUrl()."/group/$result['rel']'>$result['groupName']</a>";
    break;
    case 3:
    echo _("You received 100 credit for log in today");
  }
}
```

Comment: View logic, I agree. However, if you're going to have those strings printed out on different locations throughout the site (header, sidebar, ...), I would consider turning this into a custom CI helper, keeping things DRY.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would create a real view instead of using [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

This code is clearly part of presentation logic, which is in purview of views in MVC design pattern. Unfortunately for you CodeIgniter  is using Rails-like architecture, which means that you will have to use [helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html), thus pushing you even farther away from MVC-inspired design patterns.

Comment: In CI, "views" are just templates and "models" are basically just data mappers with some logic à la domain object. Combine this with the overpowering reach of the "controllers", and I think the author is so far removed from the MVC pattern that the use of helpers can't possibly put him any *further* away :]